# File permissions for PHP execute

Tags: php, sql, permissions

I am in the process of setting up the godaddy file permissions and I do not know what permissions to set for my PHP files. They should be able to read, write and execute effecting the SQL server. Which options should I select, the default permissions are shown in the image below.

[image]

Comment: would this allow the file to write to a database when a user signs up? e.t.c

Comment: so I should select( user - r,w,e   group -  r,e  world -   r,e)?

Comment: go through this link http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/cpanel/file_permissions.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP files should only have the EXECUTE permission for all 3 groups
php files are executed, not read, like html files for example
if you leave read, people can with some tricky methods view your actual php code and steal it, so don't leave read on .php files