# Read Permission for execute php files in linux

Tags: php, linux

I was reading about files permissions in Linux, and I have some misunderstanding about reading permission:

I have a PHP file called `a.php` with this permissions `-r--------`

so when I try to run it `PHP a.php` the files is executed

so my question is why the file is executed even the exec permission is not on?

and as I know the read permission is for reading contents for the file .

I also check this [File permissions for PHP execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28051528/file-permissions-for-php-execute) but not help.

Comment: `php` is what is being executed, which is reading the php file.

Comment: @Jonnix oh , you mean that php have exec permission ? and read permission was needed to open file and exec ?

Comment: Yes, if you found the `php` command you'd find it had a execute flag, probably for all users. Do note, I'm talking specifically about your example. It is possible to execute a php file (kind of) directly, in which case execute would be required. Different SAPIs can also work  differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`php` is the script and it has execution permission while `a.php` is just a parameter that passed to the script to be processed and as `a.php` has read permission so it can be read and processed.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed , but i want to ask , why is we need read + exec permissions for exec a file ? does exec permission not enough alone ?

Comment: System need to read the content of the script firstly to execute it.

Comment: Thanks alot dude .